# KeyError when trying to save model instance. Django

Tags: python, django, signals

KeyError when trying to save model instance.
It has to react on post_save signal than save instance...

Code:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class PlaylistEntry(models.Model):
    playlist=models.ForeignKey(Playlist)
    media=models.ForeignKey(Media)
    order=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=9000000, editable=False)
    added=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now(),editable=False )

def playlist_entry_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        entrys=PlaylistEntry.objects.filter(playlist=instance.playlist).order_by('order')
        entrys[0].save()

post_save.connect(playlist_entry_changed, PlaylistEntry)
```

Error:

```
Exception Type: KeyError at /admin/playlist/playlistentry/add/
Exception Value: 38539456
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this signal?  Right now it doesn't appear to be doing anything useful.

Comment: I just want to make autoincrement order when new entry added. End recount order when one of playlistentryes deleted. 

I see the problem. Its infinitу cicle

How can make it?

Comment: Autoincrement of key fields is already part of Django.  Why build your own?  Also.  Why not use the `save` method?  It's usually much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments what you're trying to do is update ordering.  Rather than use a signal, override the save method.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Only do this if it's the first time we're saving.
    if not self.id:
        entries = PlaylistEntry.objects.order_by('-order')
        try:
            self.order = entries[0].order + 1
        except IndexError:
            # we don't have any PlaylistEntries yet, so we just start @ 0
            self.order = 0

    super(PlaylistEntry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also, why are default your order to 9 million... shouldn't you start with 0?

Answer (score 0):

For implementig an ordering you can also have a look at [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/998/)!